# Retrieve color information from images

Tags: image, image-processing

I need to determine the amount/quality of color in an image in order to compare it with other images and recommend a user (owner of the image) maybe he needs to print it in black and white and not in color.

So far I'm analyzing the image and extracting some data of it:

- The number of different colors I find in the image
- The percentage of color in the whole page (color pixels / total pixels)

For further analysis I may need other characteristic of these images. Do you know what else is important (or I'm missing here) in image analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a missing characteristic (very important) which helped me a lot with the analysis of the images. I don't know if there is a name for that but I called it the **average color** of the image:

When I was looping over all the pixels of the image and counting each color I also retrieved the information of the RGB values and summarized all the Reds, Greens and Blues of all the pixels. Just to come up with this **average color** which, again, saved my life when I wanted to compare some kind of images.

The code is something like this:

```java
File f = new File("image.jpg");
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(f);

int tot = 0;
int red = 0;
int blue= 0;
int green = 0;
int w = im.getWidth();
int h = im.getHeight();

// Going over all the pixels
for (int i=0;i<w;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<h;j++){
       int pix = im.getRGB(i, j); // 
          if (!sameARGB(pix)) { // Compares the RGB values
              tot+=1;
              red+=pix.getRed();
              green+=pix.getGreen();
              blue+=pix.getBlue();
          }
    }
}
```

And you should get the results like this:

```java
// Percentage of color on the image
double per = (double)tot/(h*w);

// Average color <-------------
Color c = new Color((double)red/tot,(double)green/tot,(double)blue/tot);
```